# Unexpected behavior creating instance of type

Tags: .net, vb.net, type-conversion, structuremap

I have a large Windows Forms application with a large number of reports/workflows that the end user can work with.
I am using StructureMap for IoC/DI, .Net 3.5

Meta data for each of these reports/routes is represented by rows in a database.  Standard stuff like unique rowID, report name, a couple of descriptive sentences.

At the moment I have a class that is responsible for launching each report.  It is a massive Case statement that looks like this:

```
Public Sub LaunchSomething(launchRequest as LaunchItemInfo)
  Dim cmd as ICommand
  Select Case launchRequest.UniqueId
  Case 1
    cmd = New Reports.AccountsPayable.PrintChecksCommand
  Case 2
    cmd = New SomeOtherCommandClass
  ..
  Case 400
    cmd = New Report400Class
  End Select

    AppController.Commands.Invoke(cmd)
  End Sub
```

I really want to be able to use code like this:

```
Public Sub LaunchSomething(launchRequest as LaunchItemInfo)
  Dim cmd as ICommand
  Dim typ as Type
  typ = Type.GetType(launchRequest.ReportClassName, launchRequest.FileContainingReportClass)
  cmd = Activator.CreateInstance(typ)
  AppController.Commands.Invoke(cmd)
End Sub
```

These are the supporting interfaces & classes I am using.
ICommand is just a marker interface

```
Public Interface ICommand
End Interface

Public Interface ICommandHandler(Of C As ICommand)
    Sub Handle(cmd As C)
End Interface

Public Class PrintChecksCommand
    Implements ICommand
End Class
```

AppController.Commands is a CommandInvoker, the Invoke method looks like this:

```
Public Sub Invoke(Of C As ICommand)(ByVal command As C)
  Dim handlers as Generic.IList(Of IcommandHandler(Of C))
  handlers = ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances(Of ICommandHandler(Of C))()
  For each h as ICommandHandler(Of C) in handlers
    h.Handle(command)
 Next
 End Sub
```

When I use my original code with 400+ Case statements the handlers collection correctly contains 1 item.  So I know my structuremap registry is setup correctly.

When I try to use the desired code with `Activator.CreateInstance` the handlers collection is empty.

As far as I can tell in the debugger I am getting an `ICommand` of the same type passed into the Invoke method on the `CommandInvoker` when using either of the 2 methods to create the `PrintChecksCommand`

What do I need to change to be able to use the `Activator.CreateInstance(typ)` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to solving this was to add Generics to the ICommand Interface, and make use of the extra information in the CommandInvoker.

Interfaces/Classes now look like this:

```
Public Interface ICommand(Of T)  
End Interface  

Public Interface ICommandHandler(Of T as ICommand(Of T))
  Sub Handle(cmd as T)  
End Interface

Public Interface ICommandInvoker  
    Sub Invoke(Of T As ICommand(Of T))(ByVal command As ICommand(Of T))  
End Interface  

Public Class CommandInvoker  
      Implements ICommandInvoker  
    Public Sub Invoke(Of T As ICommand(Of T))(command As ICommand(Of T)) Implements ICommandInvoker.Invoke
    Dim handlers As Generic.IList(Of ICommandHandler(Of T)) = Nothing  
    handlers = ioc.GetAllInstances(Of ICommandHandler(Of T))()  
    For Each h As ICommandHandler(Of T) In handlers  
        h.Handle(command)  
    Next  
    End Sub  
End Class

Public Class DoSomethingCommand
    Implements ICommand(Of DoSomethingCommand)
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class SomethingHandler
    Implements ICommandHandler(Of DoSomethingCommand)

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Handle(cmd As DoSomethingCommand) Implements ICommandHandler(Of DoSomethingCommand).Handle
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I would take Phils code a step further and have your IOC container decorate the handler with all the commands through the constructor. Ín addition I would recommend this book by Mark Seeman http://www.amazon.com/Dependency-Injection-NET-Mark-Seemann/dp/1935182501 and his blog which you can get through http://stackoverflow.com/users/126014/mark-seemann.